# external javascript in iframe always reloading

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div with a `<script scr='highcharts.js'>` that is embedded in the code of that div.
My application will rewrite the source of that DIV every now and then, and write a bunch of new code. It will also rewrite the  tag. Every thing works fine (highcharts is working). But because of some other constraints it is quite difficult to write the  tag in the main body of the page. (It will take to long to explain exactly why... I hope my question can be answered without :-) )

The strange thing is: when I look with firebug, I can tell the script is being reloaded everytime I rewrite the source of the DIV! There is even some kind of id added to the URL:

```
/highcharts.src.js?_=1328861301862
```

I'm not doing this! I don't recognize the ID as anything in my app... It seems that every browser is doing this, so it is not specific to FF. Why is this happing, and is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: the id is probably a timestamp to force the browser to *not* cache the file. Not sure how it's getting there.

Comment: What is so hard to post some code?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wonders how I solved this: I ended up using [require.js](http://requirejs.org/). This solved the problem neatly :-)